Why I am not Getting Site Title on Google Result of Wordpress site using Yoast SEO plugin
I'm managing a WordPress website called FlutterTPoints and using Yoast SEO to optimize my pages. However, when I search for my blog posts on Google, the site name is not displayed in the search results. Instead, Google shows unrelated text like Amazon.com in the site title.
What I've Tried So Far:
Ensured the Site Title and Tagline are correctly set in Settings > General.
Configured Yoast SEO > Search Appearance:
Organization name: FlutterTPoints
Proper SEO titles and meta descriptions for individual posts.
Verified that Yoast is generating the correct schema markup using Google's Rich Results Test.
Submitted and updated my sitemap in Google Search Console.
Cleared all caches (site and browser).



You can see that I have manually configures the seo details on yoast seo plugin but the "Amazon.com" name is appearing instead of the site name "FlutterTPoints"
I have also added the site title into the Yoast seo plugin setting

The site is new to Google but has many articles it seems. Did you use the amazon url for tests perhaps?

This question is off-topic here, as 1) it's not a programming question; and 2) it's seo-related. Maybe it fits on [webmasters.se] or [wordpress.se] - but you'll need to read the guidelines for each of those Stack Exchange sites.

Thanks for your responses, @gael I haven't used the amazon url for testing.
